# Is there a way to quantify the effect of this floating-point numbers encoding on the robustness ofclassification?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, reference-request, model-request, autonomous-vehicles

This question is related to the usage of NN in critical systems (those where a failure can cause life threatening situations - autopilots for example) and the need for formal guarantees on their behavior. [Here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1702.01135) is, for example, a paper that verifies NN used in the controls of an unmanned air-vehicle.

There are numerous tools and techniques for the formal verification (not just testing and simulation, but actual mathematical proof) of, say, floating-point calculation (properties like: will not overflow, will not accumulate an error greater than x, etc).

Now take a DNN where the weights are real numbers. That is the DNN as a concept. But there is the implementation of the NN, where the weights must be encoded as floating-points ([some](http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.01025) even as low precision as 3-bits integers, apparently). And then, (faster) computation is done on these encodings. Someone might argue that you lose precision, but others might answer that it may be a good thing  since one must prevent a NN for over-fitting anyway...

Questions:

- Is there a way to quantify the effect of this encoding on the robustness/precision/stability-of-classification, in a comparable way to what we have in (non learning) software verification?
- Are there NN architectures (like Sum-Product Networks(?)) that are more amendable to offer such guarantees?

Comment: There is a lot of evidence that floating point precision is not a factor in neural networks, for example here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.7024.pdf